# Need to delete records from database and alert the ids deleted using checkbox in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom-events

I am trying to delete records in database using checkboxes in jsp page. I am new to JSP and front end so am not able to properly debug and find out how I should be actually doing it.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<form name=myname >
<table border="1">
<tr><td></td><a href="#" onclick='deleteElement();'">Delete</a>
<td><b><u>bookid</u></b></td>
<td><b><u>Author</u></b></td>
<td><b><u>title</u></b></td>
</tr>
<%try{
Connection conn = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "root");
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement st=null;
st=conn.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from book");

int i=0; while(rs.next()){ %>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="check<%=i%>" value=<%= rs.getString("bookId") %>></td>
    <td><%= rs.getString("bookId") %></td>
    <td><%= rs.getString("author") %></td>
    <td><%= rs.getString("title") %></td>
</tr><%
i++;
}
}catch(SQLException e){ System.out.println(e.getMessage()); } %>
</table>
</form>
<script LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
function deleteElement(){
    alert("hello");
    <%String id[]= new String[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    id[i]=request.getParameter("check"+i);
    }
    %>
    <%try{
    Connection conn = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "root");
    Statement st=null;
    st=conn.createStatement();
    for(int a=0;a<10;a++){
    st.executeUpdate("delete from book where bookid='"+id[a]+"'");
    }
    }catch(SQLException e){ 
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }
        %>
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got scriptlet code in your JSP.  That's a very bad idea.

I'd recommend learning JSTL and letting your JSP communicate with a servlet.  The servlet will bind and validate input parameters and interact with an object that performs the database operation for you.

The nice thing about this arrangement is that it naturally breaks your problem into pieces.  Database can be coded, debugged, tested, and put aside.